# Date error on nodejs route, getting 'NaN' or 'Invalid Date'

Tags: node.js

The goal is retrieve 1 day events from my mongoDB database.
I enter the URL: http://localhost:3000/logs/device/date/rule/DESKTOP-JJ2K67A/1624244400/60132

The timestamp i send its for example: 2021-06-21 00:00, and on my route i add one day to it and then i get the result of this day only.

The field id on my mongoDB is a timestamp format date.

my route is:

```
router.get('/device/date/rule/:device/:ts/:rule', async (req, res) => {
  let startDate = req.params.ts;
  let endDate = new Date(startDate.valueOf());
  endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 1);
  endDate = endDate.getTime();
  try {
    const logues = await logs.find({
      'agent.name': req.params.device,
      'id': {
        $gte: req.params.ts,
        $lt: endDate
      },
      'rule.id': req.params.rule
    }).sort({ 'id': -1 }).limit(15);
    res.json(logues)
  }
  catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
  }
})
```

And iam getting the log on moongose:

```
Mongoose: logs.find({ 'agent.name': 'DESKTOP-JJ2K67A', id: { '$gte': '1624244400', '$lt': 'NaN' }, 'rule.id': '60132'}, { sort: { id: -1 }, limit: 15, projection: {} })
```

Look at this at part of log:

```
id: { '$gte': '1624244400', '$lt': 'NaN' }
```

my endDate is getting result has NaN.

I already tryied to change the date format and alot other forms but it dont work, or i get NaN or i get "Invalid Date".

Iam new to nodejs, maybe its a very simple error from my part.

On fiddle it works very well, sending me the alert with the correct timestamp(code below) why on route dont work?

```
  let startDate = 1624244400;
  let endDate = new Date(startDate.valueOf());
  endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 1);
  endDate = endDate.getTime();
alert(endDate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are sending timestamp `(1624244400)` in routes for start Date, simply use this timestamp value to get next day value in timestamp format.

Check below lines of code:

```
  let startDateTs = req.params.ts; // your timestamp
  startDateTs = parseInt(startDateTs) * 1000; //convert to milliseconds 
  const sDate = new Date(startDateTs);
  const eDate = new Date(startDateTs + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); //Add One day milliseconds
```

Now use `sDate` and `eDate` in your query (timestamp in milliseconds) which should be accepted by mongoose.

[DO VOTE THIS ANSWER IF IT'S HELPFUL TO YOU...]

Comment: Worked fine. I just added the .getTime() on both dates to get unix timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to initialize a date from time value or timestamp. The parameter of [`Date() constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#:%7E:text=Time%20value%20or%20timestamp%20number) must be an integer value representing the number of `milliseconds` since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.

Wraps the date in the query by a `new Date()`.
Check out this link for more information: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/

You can change your route to the following:

```js
router.get('/device/date/rule/:device/:ts/:rule', async (req, res) => {
  let startDateTs = req.params.ts;
  startDateTs = parseInt(startDateTs) * 1000; //convert to milliseconds 
  const startDate = new Date(startDateTs);
  const endDate = new Date(startDateTs + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); //a day have (24 * 60 *60 *1000) milliseconds 
  try {
    const logues = await logs.find({
      'agent.name': req.params.device,
      'id': {
        $gte: startDate,
        $lt: endDate
      },
      'rule.id': req.params.rule
    }).sort({ 'id': -1 }).limit(15);
    res.json(logues)
  }
  catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
  }
})
```

Comment: Worked fine. I just added the .getTime() on both dates to get unix timestamp.